# Hiding specific navigation menus from specific roles in admin panel

Tags: menus, user-roles

So what I'm trying to do is make 13 different user roles on my website and I have 13 different navigation menus. Each of these menus is displayed on the front end on separate pages.

I need to let each of the user roles to edit only their own navigation menu and not any of the others.

I have only seen plugins and tutorials on how to hide menu items from the Wordpress Admin menu but not a single tutorial for hiding Navigation menus from specific roles (under Appearance -> Menus)

Comment: You would need to use custom capabilities to your roles. Then you can specify these capabilities when adding the menu pages.

Comment: WP's Menu capabilities are not this granular. Each role can either edit menu items, or not edit any menu items - if you give them access to one menu you're giving them access to all menus. You may need to think of some other way such as a custom settings page to allow them to manage the content they need to access without being able to access anything else.